Running into "Target page, context or browser has been closed" issue
The below code is my Playwright test function
    test("@Login @Testing Sign In Page Test", async ({ page }) => {
        console.log("Sign In Page Test");
 
        const pageManager = new pageObjectManager(page);
        const homePage = pageManager.getHomePage();
        const loginPage = pageManager.getLoginPage();
        const signInPage = pageManager.getSignInPage();

        // await homePage.goToHomePage();
        await page.goto("https://magento.softwaretestingboard.com/");

        // await loginPage.goToSignInPage();
        console.log(await page.title());
        await page.locator("//li[@class='authorization-link']").first().click();

        // await signInPage.validateLandingOnSignInPage();
        console.log(await page.title());
        await expect(page).toHaveTitle("Customer Login");
    });

This worked for me a few months ago but now, when I am trying to rerun the test case, I run into the below error
Error: page.title: Target page, context or browser has been closed

      34 |
      35 |      // await signInPage.validateLandingOnSignInPage();
    > 36 |      console.log(await page.title());
         |                             ^
      37 |      await expect(page).toHaveTitle("Customer Login");
      38 | });
      39 |


Even when I place the code in functions mentioned in comments just above them, I see the issue.
I am not sure what is causing this fresh issue. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Please don´t use css or xpath as locators. It is much easier to use page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Sign In' }).click()

Which version of Playwright and Chromium are you using?

I tested you code and it works
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://magento.softwaretestingboard.com/');
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle("Home Page");
  await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Sign In' }).click();
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle("Customer Login");
});

If you want to use consol.log you must think about using ConsoleMessage. There is an issue mentioned right here

Tried your code only to see the same error:
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";
test("@Login @Testing Sign In Page Test", async ({ page }) => {
await page.goto("https://magento.softwaretestingboard.com/");
await expect(page).toHaveTitle("Home Page");
await page.getByRole("link", { name: "Sign In" }).click();
await expect(page).toHaveTitle("Customer Login");
});

maybe adding a wait for domcontentloaded before getting a page title will help
 await this.page.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');


Please don´t use waitForLoadState. expect has already have an auto-wait
